# Informatica Designer (9.6.1.) Autolink wildcard

Tags: wildcard, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Does anyone know if there is a wildcard for prefix/suffix in the Autolink feature?

Autolink: By Name - More - Enter prefix

eg.

Expression port name:   abc_D1001_This1

Target port name: This1

Constant is the part: abc_Dxxxx_

Where I'd like to wildcard the x characters. I've tried * and %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. 
But out of curiosity: the wildcard matches multiple characters, right? So - possibly - it could match multiple ports. Which one should be chosen and linked to target port? How do you think this should work?

Comment: Hi Maciejg, I came to the realisation after much trial & error and no documentation hinting it might be.  I think we might misunderstand each other on wildcard.  I mean a single character.  So * would be match any single whilst ** would be 2 consecutive chars.  The end part of the ports are different so you could have D****_AB and D*****_CD. Using the prefix D*****_

Comment: For the record I ended up pulling both source ports into individual expressions and then right clicking on ONE expression to 'Create Target & SQL'.  You can then strip the SQL prefix/name however you want and then Autolink the exp & target by position.  For the other exp & port your stuffed & have to manually link. You could possibly create SQL for both and merge both SQL, using placeholder ports in each expression so that you can Autolink by position. That felt prone to greater frustration tho.